# Javascript button onclick doesn't work on first click

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, modal-dialog

I know similar questions have been asked before but I'm new to Javascript and none of the answers could help me solve my problem.

What I'm trying to do: 
four buttons that open modals

but like the title already says, is there no reaction until the buttons have been clicked twice.

Here's my html:

```
<a id="myBtn" class="btn" href="javascript:void();" onclick="termsFct(this)">View full terms</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<span id="x" class="close">&times;</span>
<h1 class="contract">sample heading</h1>
<h2 class="contract">sample heading</h2>
<p class="fullContract">sample text</p>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<a id="myBtn2" class="btn" href="javascript:void();" onclick="termsFct(this)">View full terms</a>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<span id="x2" class="close">&times;</span>
<h1 class="contract">sample heading</h1>
<h2 class="sample heading</h2>
<p class="fullContract">sample text</p>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<a id="myBtn3" class="btn" href="javascript:void();" onclick="termsFct(this)">View full terms</a>
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<span id="x3" class="close">&times;</span>
<h1 class="contract">sample heading</h1>
<h2 class="contract">sample heading</h2>
<p class="fullContract">sample text</p>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<a id="myBtn4" class="btn" href="javascript:void();" onclick="termsFct(this)">View full terms</a>
<div id="myModal4" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<span id="x4" class="close">&times;</span>
<h1 class="contract">sample heading</h1>
<h2 class="contract">sample heading</h2>
<p class="fullContract">sample text</p>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

and here's the Javascript:

```
/*------------------------modal------------------------*/
function termsFct(buttonElement) {
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal3');
var modal4 = document.getElementById('myModal4');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("myBtn3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("myBtn4");

var span = document.getElementById("x");
var span2 = document.getElementById("x2");
var span3 = document.getElementById("x3");
var span4 = document.getElementById("x4");
/*------------------------contract visibility------------------------*/
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}
btn2.onclick = function() {
modal2.style.display = "block";
}
btn3.onclick = function() {
modal3.style.display = "block";
}
btn4.onclick = function() {
modal4.style.display = "block";
}
/*------------------------close if x was clicked------------------------*/
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
span2.onclick = function() {
modal2.style.display = "none";
}
span3.onclick = function() {
modal3.style.display = "none";
}
span4.onclick = function() {
modal4.style.display = "none";
}
/*------------------------close if clicked outside------------------------*/
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.scrollTop = 0;
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
else if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.scrollTop = 0;
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}
else if (event.target == modal3) {
    modal3.scrollTop = 0;
    modal3.style.display = "none";
}
else if (event.target == modal4) {
    modal4.scrollTop = 0;
    modal4.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem and even better help me shorten the Javascript.

thanks in advance
Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The termsFct method is already fired when the button is clicked. so no need of an onclick inside this method.

Replace the btn.onclick section with the below code and add more cases.

```
Switch(buttonelement.id){
    Case btn1:
           Modal.style.display="block";
    Break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, why didn't I think of that.